# Does HTTP Live Streaming Support Rewind?

Tags: ios, http, safari, streaming

Is there a way to do rewind with an HLS implementation?

Here is a link of what HLS is: https://developer.apple.com/streaming/

Wikipedia says yes: "Later versions of the protocol also provide for trick mode fast-forward and rewind and integration of subtitle" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming

So how do I implement a rewind in HLS?

Answer (score 1):

You can use AVPlayer to play an HTTP Live Stream video. It will allow you to seek in reverse just like you would seek forward. So in that sense, you can rewind. However, due to the compressed nature of the stream, rewind is quite slow, because it needs to rewind all the way back to the closest keyframe and then interpolate forward to your seek point.

If you're looking for a smooth rewind, it really isn't possible with any stream that is compressed (for the reasons stated above). But you can get decent "rewind" performance if your movie file lives on the device.

I would suggested creating an AVPlayerItem from your HLS and then play that item in an AVPlayer. Experiment a bit to see what the results are and go from there.

Comment: Thanks for the response, what about in safari?

Comment: What about in Safari? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I want to support rewind of an HLS stream inside the safari web browser, is this possible?

Comment: Still not sure what you're getting at. Do you want to create an app that opens Safari to play a live stream?